# Google Colab MIP outputs 0; but doesnt give an error. What is wrong?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, or-tools

I am trying to solve a relatively simple MIP problem with Google Colab (I am new to colab). The problem formulation looks like:

[image: MIP problem formulation]

Translating the formulation into a code (using a distance matrix uploaded from excel), I dont get erros, but the objective value is zero. So that is not correct. Does someone know how I can check what I am doing wrong? Or for example in Gurobi you can call the m.write function, which will give insight in what the code does during the running process. I cant find a similar call in google colab.

This is the code (some spaces can be messed up due to copying):

```
!pip install --upgrade ortools
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

from google.colab import files
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io


uploaded = files.upload()
for key in uploaded.keys():
  print('user uploaded file ''{name}'' with length {length} bytes'.format(name=key, 
length=len(uploaded[key])))

data = pd.read_excel('test_v1.xlsx', index_col='Row Labels')
print(data)


solver = pywraplp.Solver('groupproject', pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

#create variables
x = {} #binary to determine if rdc j is opened or not
z = {} #binary to determine if cdc k is opened or not 
y = {} #binary to determine if shipment i is assigned to rdc j
w = {} #binary to determine if rdc j is supplied by cdc k
d = {} #distances




for j in range(2, len(data)): #set of possible RDC locations
   x[j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x' + str(j))
   numShops = len(data.iloc[j])
   for i in range(numShops): #set of shops
     y[i,j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'y' + str(i) + '_' + str(j))


for k in range(0, 2): #set of CDC locations (will all be used)
   z[k] = solver.IntVar(0,1, 'z' + str(k))
   for j in range(2, len(data)):
     w[j,k] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'w' + str(j) + '_' + str(k))

for j in range(len(data)):
  for i in range(len(data.iloc[j])):
    d[i,j] = data.iloc[j][i]

for i in range(numShops):
  for j in range(2, len(data)):
    solver.Add(y[i,j] <= x[j])

for j in range(2, len(data)):
  for k in range(0, 2):
    solver.Add(w[j,k] <= z[k])

solver.Add(solver.Sum(x[j] for j in range(2, len(data))) == 3)
solver.Add(solver.Sum(z[k] for k in range(0,2)) == 2)

for i in range(numShops):
  solver.Add(solver.Sum(y[i,j] for j in range(2, len(data))) == 1)

for j in range(2, len(data)):
  solver.Add(solver.Sum(w[j,k] for k in range(0, 2)) == x[j])

objective1 = solver.Sum(d[i,j]*y[i,j] for i in range(numShops) for j in range(2, len(data)))
objective2 = solver.Sum(d[j,k]*w[j,k] for j in range(2,len(data)) for k in range(0,1))
objective = objective1 + objective2
solver.Minimize(objective)

result = solver.Solve()

#displaying the results
print(solver.Objective().Value())
#for i in x:
# if x[i].solution_value() > 0:
#  print(str('x') + str('_') + str(i) + ':' + str(x[i].solution_value()))
#for i,j in y:
#   if y[i,j].solution_value() > 0:
#  print(str('y') + str('_') + str(i) + str('_') + str(j) + ':' + str(y[i,j].solution_value()))
```

Can you spot any bugs here?